# Ingresar dos lenguajes y realizar concatenaciones en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hola buenos dias tengo un problema con este codigo en el cual las concatenaciones por pantalla las imprime solo que al final me sale una coma que no va:
Lo que muestra por pantalla: {canta,casa,manta,masa,}

Este es el enunciado:

Dado dos lenguajes como entradas (L1 y L2) y un texto que contenga  concatenaciones que pueden obtenerse de los lenguajes de entrada, verificar que las concatenaciones ingresadas se correspondan con los lenguajes L1 y L2.
Por ejemplo:

```
L1 = {ca,ma}
L2 = {nta,sa}
Lo que deberia mostrar: {canta,casa,manta,masa}

def split(Lenguaje):
    separador=",.:;}?{ "
    Vectorpalabra=[]
    temp=""
    for n in Lenguaje:
        if n in separador:
            if temp!="":
                Vectorpalabra.append(temp)
                temp=""
        else:
            temp+=n
    if temp:
        Vectorpalabra.append(temp)
    return Vectorpalabra

a=0
ConcatenaLen=""

while a<2:
    Lenguaje = str(input("Ingresa un lenguaje"))
    if Lenguaje[0:1]=="{" and Lenguaje[len(Lenguaje)-1:len(Lenguaje)]=="}":
        print("Es un lenguaje")
        if a==1:
            Lenguaje1 = split(Lenguaje) 
        else:
            Lenguaje2 = split(Lenguaje)
        a+=1            
    else:
        print("No es un lenguaje")    

for i in range(0,len(Lenguaje1)):
    for j in range(0,len(Lenguaje2)):
        ConcatenaLen = ConcatenaLen+Lenguaje2[i]+Lenguaje1[j]+","
        CombinacionLenguaje = "{"f"{ConcatenaLen}""}"

print(CombinacionLenguaje)
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es un patrón recurrente: generar una cadena a partir de una lista, insertado separadores, evitando un separador antes del primer elemento o después del último.

Una opción es en cada ciclo anteponer el separador a cada elemento antes de concatenarlo a la línea en formación. El separador parte vacio, y se inicializa al final de cada iteración:

```
separador = ""
cadena = ""
for elemento in ["A","B","C"]:
   cadena = cadena + separador + elemento
   separador = ","
print(cadena) => A,B,C
```

En la primera iteración, `separador` está vacio, por lo que `cadena` queda en "A".

A continuación se inicializa `separador` con el caracter deseado (`","`).

En la segunda y siguiente iteración, se va insertando un separador entre cada elemento.

Aplicado a tu caso:

```
L1 = ["ca", "ma"]
L2 = ["nta", "sa"]
ConcatenaLen=""
separador = ""
for i in range(0,len(L1)):
    for j in range(0,len(L2)):
        ConcatenaLen = ConcatenaLen + separador + L1[i]+L2[j]
        CombinacionLenguaje = "{"f"{ConcatenaLen}""}"
        separador = ","
print(ConcatenaLen)
```

Ojo: Corregí la expresión para evaluar `ConcatenaLen`.

produce

```
canta,casa,manta,masa
```

Answer (score 0):

hay muchas formas de hacerlo, otra sería:

```
L1 = ["ca", "ma"]
L2 = ["nta", "sa"]
L3=[]
for x in L1:
    for y in L2:
        L3.append(f"{x}{y}")
print(",".join(L3))
```

donde creo una lista y le agrego la concatenación de los valores de las listas y después por medio de join los paso a cadena
Lo mismo en una línea:

```
print(",".join([f"{x}{y}" for x in L1 for y in L2]))
```